# In Mongoose how do I find a document based on a date range in a subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, subdocument

I have a node.js api, using mongoose, and mongo and an already existing database. I need to add the ability to query based on a subdocument date range. I can get the aggregation query to work in MongoDB using Robo3T but I cannot get the same query to work in nodejs/mongoose.

Note that although I do not show it in the code snippets it has to be in an aggregation pipeline as it is being joined to other values.

I have gotten it to work in MongoDB using Robo3T and the following

```js
db.getCollection('sample').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            chronology:{
                $elemMatch: {
                    timestamp: { $gte: new Date('2018-10-30') },
                    state: 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ]);
```

Inside of mongoose I have tried, using the date string directly, converting it to a date and using that, converting the date to an ISOString, converting the date to a timestamp, and passing in as a string 'new Date("' + date + '")' or just date or ISODate or new ISODate, all of which always returns 0 results with no errors, (and in Mongo I get results so there IS documents in that range).

I also tried unwind despite it not being what I want as it duplicates the root documents

chronology is an array of subdocuments, timestamp is a Date and state is an Int32

MCVE

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoMemoryServer = require('mongodb-memory-server-core').MongoMemoryServer;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var chronologySchema = new Schema({
    timestamp: {type: Date, default: Date.now(), required: true},
    state: {type: Number, required: true, default: 0},
},{_id: false});

var sampleSchema = new Schema({
    text: {type: String, required: true, default: ''},
    chronology: {type: [chronologySchema], required: true, default: []},
});

var model = mongoose.model('sample', sampleSchema);

var db = {};

db.init = async function(){
  const mongod = new MongoMemoryServer();

  const uri = await mongod.getConnectionString();
  // const port = await mongod.getPort();
  // const dbPath = await mongod.getDbPath();
  // const dbName = await mongod.getDbName();
  mongoose.connect(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true
    });

    db.Sample = model

    var s = new db.Sample();
    s.text = "Hello1";
    var c = {
        timestamp: "2019-07-11",
        state: 1
    };

    var c2 = {
        timestamp: "2018-07-11",
        state: 2
    };

    s.chronology = [c, c2];

    s.save(function(err, result){
        var q = {};
        q.chronology = {
            $elemMatch: {
                timestamp: { $gte: new Date('2019-07-10') },
                state: 2
            }
        };

        db.Sample.aggregate([
            {
                $match: q
            },
        ]).exec(function(e, r){
            console.log(e, r);
            process.exit();
        });
    });
};

db.init();
```

Requires mongoose and mongodb-memory-server to run

I expect to see results instead I get returned an empty array with no errors in the console

Comment: create [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean) to get help faster or to get any help at all

Comment: I've created an MCVE, note that you have to run it locally because it requires mongo

Comment: you are asking for "fix this", instead of "how does this work?"

Comment: No I'm asking how do I do this, because if there is a better way to do it I'm not sure what it is and am open to suggestions.